# Is there a useful way to check data types between platforms

Tags: .net, sql-server, vb.net

I am doing a data importer project from which uses OLEDB to get Excel data and then we need to push it into the SQL SERVER backend db through our VB.NET project. The user of the importer defines which source fields go into which destination field.

So we could have a (Source) VB.NET [System.String] type selected from our drop down menu against our (Destination) nvarchar field, this will all work fine. The problem is there is nothing to stop the user doing something like selecting a (Source) VB.NET [System.DateTime] field and trying to put that in a Destination nvarchar field. There is lots of this work that will need doing. I wondered if anyone has a good idea on a best approach for this. I suppose I am trying to avoid manually type lots of IF Statements. I figured there may well be something in .NET that already handles this process.

Comment: Ultimately, Excel's grasp of data "types" is tenuous at best (it has formatting, which is almost but not completely the same thing) and OLE DB is *really* fond of guessing at the correct types to use based on contents, regardless of the formatting applied in Excel (and it frequently gets it wrong). There is no built-in "correct Excel sheet to SQL Server table importer" in the framework, and typing is but one aspect -- there is nothing to stop the user from importing `CustomerName` as `City`, even if the types *do* match.

Comment: Excel has four actual types: number (double-precision floating point), text, boolean and array. All the rest is obtained by formatting these primitive values, including (unfortunately) date/time values, which are formatted numbers. It is often indispensable to allow the user to specify what the "actual" type of the value is supposed to be (and its format), because automated guesses often fail, and (say) importing every number as a `FLOAT` would be technically correct but often lead to unwanted results.

Comment: I see how I have written it that maybe it comes across in a different way than I intended. Basically the user is not determining the type. They are just picking the field name. So for example they might pick a source name called First Name which is of type VB.NET [System.String]. They might try to put it in a DateOfBirth field which will be MSSQL dateTime2 type. They won't know the types only the field names. I'm looking for a simple way to test and fail validation for an example such as this.

Comment: If you're content with the data type inference of OLE DB and you just want to match managed types with SQL types, a simple way of doing so is putting the results of a `SELECT TOP(0) * FROM TABLE` into a `DataTable` (using `DataTable.Load()`, for example), and getting the `DataType` of its `Columns`. As the mapping between T-SQL and managed types is not exactly 1-1 either, this is not perfect, but at least it does the heavy lifting for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can fall back on SQL Server's implicit type conversions for most of the heavy lifting, performing explicit mapping and conversion in .NET only for the cases where there isn't an appropriate type conversion, or you require special logic to deal with strangeness in the Excel data.

Notice how SQL Server supports implicit copnversions from `NVARCHAR` to almost every other type.  So a command of the form

```
insert into [t] (a,b,c,d) values (@a,@b,@c,@d)
```

with `NVARCHAR` parameters will typically "just work".

The following illustration shows all explicit and implicit data type conversions that are allowed for SQL Server system-supplied data types.:

[image]

Comment: Be careful with this, though. Although implicit conversions from `NVARCHAR` to just about anything else are possible, the results are by no means always useful, obvious or actually allowed at runtime. This is a particular issue when implicitly converting strings to date/time values (e.g. `31/12/2004` will not be accepted by most servers), but there are plenty of other fascinating edge cases as well (converting the empty string to `INT` is allowed, for example -- the result is `0`, not `NULL`). It's just another layer to be aware of.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/sql-server-data-type-mappings